# nesting varstatus into var as index for method in jstl foreach

Tags: foreach, jstl, var, taglib

Is there a way to use varstatus as index (integer param) for var's method in jstl foreach loop in jsp pages?

I want something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${pizza1.getFeltetlist()}" var="aktpizza" varStatus="index" >

        <tr>
            <td>${index.index+1}</td>
            <td>${aktpizza.nev}</td>
            <td>${aktpizza.ar}</td>
            <td><a href="/PizzaOrderMVC/add/${aktpizza.getaFeltet(${index.index+1})}">Add</a></td>
        </tr>

    </c:forEach>
```

So getaFeltet(int i) method requires an int parameter and I want to pass the actual index of varstatus. All other fields above are populated correctly. What should be the correct syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't and don't need to nest `${...}` in each other. Just have one.

```
<a href="/PizzaOrderMVC/add/${aktpizza.getaFeltet(index.index+1)}">Add</a>
```

Comment: I already tried that.
In that case it throws error:

"javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class pizzaorder.Feltet.getaFeltet(java.lang.Integer)"

In this case the issue is that I want to use a jstl variable as parameter inside an other jstl variable

Answer (score 0):

This may not help your exact case but I've found that if you are trying to get a value in the jsp, this will not work:

> ${List.get(varStatus.index)}

but this will

> ${List[varStatus.index]}

In other words, you can't pass the status index into a function call, but you can use it to get an item at that index in a list.

If you can pass the results of aktpizza.getaFeltet() as a list, you should be able to use this technique.